# how to declare list and later add items from other deep function

Tags: c#, list, function, addition

Hello i have class called X, my declared item is:

```
{
    private Bitmap newBitmap;
    private Rectangle rect;
    public List<string,int[]> alphabetletters = new List<string,int[]>();
```

Next i have constructor X, and some functions wichi will be used while initalize constructor:

```
public X(Bitmap bmp)
{
    oloadlet2list();
    //...
}
```

In function "onloadlet2list() i search files, i get name (string) and pixel value array [26*26].
I would like to add in that function onloadlet2list, by:

```
alphabetletters.add(name,valuearray)
```

Unfortunatelly intelisens shows me that i cannot use 'add'.
What do i do wrong? Do i do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Dictionary instead of a List for storing key value pairs.

```
 public IDictionary<string,int[]> alphabetletters = new Dictionary<string,int[]>();
```

Comment: Should i declare new object in that function by: alphabetletters = new Dictionary<string,int[]>(); ?

Comment: you can initialize the dictionary like that in the constructor or in the class declaration. If you initialize it within your function you will get a new dictionary everytime it's called which is probably not what you want. Within your function you can add to it using alphabetletters.Add(name, value).